# heroku[router]: Error H14 (No web processes running) -> GET .herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=

Tags: python, django, heroku

I pushed my application to heroku and when I run `heroku open` I get an application error

I checked my logs and this was one of the error prints:

> (2012-08-01T22:20:28+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H14 (No web processes running) -> GET wawacom-trotroapp.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes)

The app is a django app designed with a sqlite3. Can anysomebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h14-no-web-processes-running

Looks like you need to scale up your web processes;

heroku ps:scale web=1

Answer (score 0):

This should help. Follow the guide from Heroku. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django